# Is there any deep reason that 23456789 is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was recently coding a prime factorization function and wanted to test that it could factor large numbers reasonably well. Arbitrarily, I slid my finger across the number pad, and got 23456789 as a test input. Surprisingly, it was prime!

Was this just a strange coincidence, or is there any deeper number theoretic structure that leads to this result.

Past research: all I've been able to do is confirm that 23456789 is indeed prime and is the largest prime with digits in ascending order. https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/23456789.html

Comment: Have you tried other bases -- if there is a deep reason, I think it unlikely that  base 10 is anything special.  For example, what is the largest prime with ascending hexadecimal digits (base 16)? I'l bet it is not 23456789ABCDEF.

Comment: @MarkFischler: I was with you on this one, but I thought I'd check. If the string-and-glue lash-up I just used for testing primality is right, 23456789ABCDEF in hex (=9927935178558959 in decimal) **is** prime (and hence is the largest prime with ascending hex digits).

Comment: This [hex-to-decimal converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) and this [primality tester](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) confirm my calculations.

Comment: I'm certain the really important number-theoretic properties of a number (like divisibility) are independent of their representation in some uninteresting number base, so... Questions like this are just entertainment for people wanting to be entertained.

Comment: its the same deep reason that $11111111111111111111111$ is prime !

Comment: @ProfessorVector I agree: if the reason is *deep*, it must be independent of the representation. The base-$9$ representation of $23456789$ is $48121588$ that shows no interesting pattern. What's the deep reason for $10$ to be prime? That the radix is prime.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with these comments that facts relating to particular number bases are uninteresting and just for entertainment. Are primes with just two non-zero base 2 digits uninteresting? The fact that 123456789 is not prime (and that its analogue in any other even base is not prime) is not deep, but finding out why it's true is an instructive exercise.

Comment: Building from @Rob Arthan's observation for the base 16 analogue, I don't feel that it would be fair to say that a deep reason, if there is one, would be necessarily independent from the base. For example, a result that holds for all bases with some common property P, in which base 10 and base 16 share P would be deep imo.

Comment: Well, my personal opinion isn't all that important. Let's the community decide: will this question just get a lot of lemmings upvotes, will it get a lot of chatty comments, or will it get **substantial answers**?

Comment: Probably , it is a coincidence. But an $8$-digit random number is more likely prime then one would expect intuitively. The probability is about $5.7$%. If the last digit is $1,3,7$ or $9$ , the probability increases to about $14.2$%. So about $1$ out of $7$ random $8$-digit numbers ending with digit $1,3,7$ or $9$, are prime!

Comment: About your question, I don't know. Here there is a miscellaneous result (I don't know if it was in the literature), and I hope that there are no mistakes in this my *Claim*: Let $\pi(x)$ the prime-counting function, and we denote its $k$-fold compostion as $\pi^k(x)$. We denote your prime as $\text{ prime}$, and notice that has $8$ digits. Then $\pi^7(\text{prime})$ is the first (even) perfect number, $\pi^8(\text{prime})$ is the first odd prime, and $\pi^9(\text{prime})$ is the first (the unique) even prime number. Was this just a strange coincidence? Who knows? Good week.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: you will need to consult posterity as well as the contemporary community: for all we know, there may be a classification of prime numbers that gives a systematic explanation why the OP's number 23456789ABCDEF is prime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not an answer, but in base $n$ that number is 
$$ a_n=\frac{2n^{n-1}-n^{n-2}-n^2+n-1}{(n-1)^2}$$
Which is prime for $n=3,4,6,10,16,18,36$ and no other $n\leq 500$. $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac 1{\ln(a_n)}$ converges, so by a heuristic following from the prime number theorem this sequence probably has only finitely many primes.

Comment: Nice answer!  How did you find that formula?

Comment: @Qudit: Write it as $\sum_{h=0}^{n-3}n^h(n-h-1)$ and use the formulas for $\sum_nx^n$ and $\sum_nnx^n$.

Comment: Selecting this as the accepted answer because I find it persuasive evidence that there is likely no deeper result and the given sequence does not seem to be indicative of a known pattern: (c.f. https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C4%2C6%2C10%2C16%2C18%2C36&language=english&go=Search )

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.-Here something I like and and maybe related to the problem proposed (note that with this definition the coefficient $a$ can be extended to be non-digit).

Define

$$P_n(x)=\sum_{2\le a\le n} ax^{n-a}$$

The polynomials $P_n(x)$ have degree $n-2$ and can be defined by recurrence via
$$P_{n+1}(x)=xP_n(x)+(n+1);\space P_2(x)=2$$ This way one has

$$P_9(10)=\color{red}{23456789}\\P_9(4)=50969,\text{ prime }\\P_9(2)=757,\text{ prime}$$ Besides with exception of $P_6$ for which $P_6(n)$ is composite for $1\le n\le 10$ one has the following primes
for $1\le n\le 10$
$$\begin{cases}P_8(5)=43943\\P_8(3)=2729\\P_7(3)=907\\P_5(2)=41\\P_5(6)=569\\P_4(3)=31\\P_4(9)=193\\P_3(1)=5\\P_3(2)=7\\P_3(4)=11\\P_3(5)=13\\P_3(7)=17\\P_3(8)=19\\P_3(10)=23\\P_2(n)=2\text{ for all } n\end{cases}$$

Comment: I forgot to mention that $4843^2\lt 23456789\lt 4844^2$ where $4843^2=2345\cdot10^4+4649$ where $4649$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

As posed, I would say that the answer to your question is no.

Say we are given just a single positive integer $n$, in your question $n = 23456789$. In this case there is no "deep reason" for $n$ to be prime. Either $n$ is prime or not, it is what it is.

On the other hand, suppose we are given a random integer $1 \leq n \leq N$. Then it follows from PNT that the probability that $n$ is prime is approximately $1 / \log N$. In other words, it is very likely that $n$ is not prime.

It seems your question is motivated by the pattern in the base $10$ expansion of $n$, with increasing digits in base $10$. You could ask questions about the set of such integers (how likely are they to be prime, are there infinitely many primes of this form, etc.). But for a specific integer there is not really anything to say.